# adding Objects to a linked list

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

I need to implement a combination of 2 methods that add wagon objects to a linked list of wagons.
But i dont understand how to build it. Every wagon object has an attribute that references the next wagon( null at start). So i guess i have to change that reference when i add a new waggon. But how can i know where and how to add the waggon and how do i get a waggon in between of 2 others...
if the train can be added is checked by the public method but how do i actually add the train with the helpermethod? Or do i actually put it in the locomotive class?

i cant put a dangerousgoods=true waggon together with passengerwagons
and passengerwagons are always at the start of the train

```
package edu.hm.cs.swe2.trains;

public class Wagon {

    private int wagonNumber;
    private boolean isPassengerWagon;
    private boolean carriesDangerousGoods;
    public Wagon nextWagon;

    public Wagon(boolean isPassengerWagon, boolean carriesDangerousGoods) {
        if (isPassengerWagon == true && carriesDangerousGoods == true) {
            this.carriesDangerousGoods = false;
            System.out.println("passengerwagon cant handle dangerous goods");
        } else
            this.isPassengerWagon = isPassengerWagon;
        this.carriesDangerousGoods = carriesDangerousGoods;
        this.setWagonNumber(0);
        this.setNextWagon(null);

    }

    public boolean isPassengerWagon() {
        return isPassengerWagon;
    }

    public boolean isCarriesDangerousGoods() {
        return carriesDangerousGoods;
    }

    public void setWagonNumber(int wagonNumber) {
        this.wagonNumber = wagonNumber;
    }

    public void setNextWagon(Wagon nextWagon) {
        this.nextWagon = nextWagon;
    }

    public void printWagon(int level) {
        if (level == 3) {
            if (nextWagon == null)
                System.out.println("**********");
        } else if (level == 2) {
            if (this.isPassengerWagon == false && this.carriesDangerousGoods == true) {
                System.out.println("* f" + this.wagonNumber + " dg *");
            } else if (this.isPassengerWagon == false && this.carriesDangerousGoods == false) {
                System.out.println("* f" + this.wagonNumber + "    *");
            } else if (this.isPassengerWagon == true) {
                System.out.println("* p" + this.wagonNumber + "    *");
            }
        } else if (level == 1) {
            System.out.println("**********->");
        } else if (level == 0) {
            System.out.println(" ***  *** ");
        }

    }

    public boolean trainCarriesDangerousGoods() {
        if (this.carriesDangerousGoods == true) {
            return true;
        } else if (this.nextWagon == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return nextWagon.trainCarriesDangerousGoods();
        }
    }

    public boolean trainHasPassengerWagons() {
        if (this.isPassengerWagon == true) {
            return true;
        } else if (this.nextWagon == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return nextWagon.trainHasPassengerWagons();
        }
    }

    public Wagon addWagon(Wagon newWagon) {
        if (this.trainCarriesDangerousGoods() == true && newWagon.isPassengerWagon() == true) {
            System.out.println("cant add Passenger wagon to a train with dangerous goods");
        }
        if (newWagon.carriesDangerousGoods == true && this.trainHasPassengerWagons() == true) {
            System.out.println("cant add dangerous goods to a train with passengerwaggons");
        } else {
            addWagon(this.wagonNumber, newWagon);
        }
        return newWagon;

    }

    private void addWagon(int wagonNumber, Wagon newWagon) {

    }
}
```

```
package edu.hm.cs.swe2.trains;

public class Locomotive {

    public int locomotiveCount;
    public int steamLocomotiveCount;
    MotivePower Propulsion;

    public Locomotive(MotivePower Propulsion) {
        this.Propulsion = Propulsion;
        locomotiveCount++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Wagon` should not point to the next `Wagon`.  Create an inner class `Node` in the `LinkedList<T>` class that has a next pointer as well as others.  The `Node` class should be something like the following:

```
class Node  {
   T object;

   Node next;
   Node previous; // optional depending on linked list type.
}
```

The `LinkedList` would be of type `Wagon`. 
    E.g. `LinkedList<Wagon> list = new LinkedList<>();` and the `Wagon` instance would be placed in the `object` field of the node.

Comment: and the linked list is implemented in the Locomotive constructor? (i need a new list for every new train) and then i add the append method in the Node class and use it in the private void class of wagon.java?

Comment: For a given `linkedList` you keep adding nodes with the `Wagon` object and then `linking` them via the next reference  This means you need to keep a reference to the first `node` so you can iterate thru the list.